# Why did the earth not get destroyed in Independence day: Resurgence?

Tags: independence-day-resurgence

Why is the earth not destroyed when the grand mothership lands on earth?

Its size is definitely bigger than the last one. It is so huge. The only damage the earth receives is on it's surface and some minor gravitational anomaly. The ship is bigger and wider than the moon (not sure if it's heavier). Shouldn't the earth be cracked at least or have received more damaged?

[image]

Comment: Completely randomly, this question got used as background in a "toptenz" video.   See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJunwbvkzAU&t=290

Answer (score 7):

As we saw in the film, it's mostly empty space inside.

[image]

Yes, this is fan-art, but anyone who stayed awake during this part of the film would remember there's an awful lot of nothing on the inside of the mother ship....

**TL;DR**: Because America is awesome.

Comment: If it's wide enough to span the Atlantic (c.3500miles)...it's as wide as the Moon (c3500**km**)....but yes, ***mass/speed*** would be the important factors. - http://independenceday.wikia.com/wiki/Harvester_Mothership?file=Independence_Day_%286%29.jpg

Comment: @Paulie_D - Dang, you're right.  Darned real-world facts....

Answer (score 2):

It's large enough to exert a significant amount of gravity on small ship that has exhibited significant thrust enough reach escape velocity in Earth gravity. This makes it massive enough that it should have caused significant disruption to the Earth, or at the very least much more than pictured. This is just one of many scientific problems with the movie.